# how to sort the following

Tags: python, sorting

Please note that I have tried to use the answers provided on this forum, plus other web sources before posting this. I'm pretty much a beginner.

Using Py 2.7.10

```
A = [9,3,7]
B = [5,1,8]
C = [1,2,1]

D = [A,B,C]
```

How can I first 1) sort by A(ascending), 2) by B(ascending) and 3) by C(ascending). In this case the values are A (x-coordinate), B (Y-coordinate) and C (z-coordinate). I have tried using a function, but it rearanged the A, B and C variables, however I would like the first element of both A, B, and C to stick together since they belong to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you provide sample output, please?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm

Comment: I would like to have my data A, B and C sorted based on A (ascending), then I would like the rows with these same A values to be sorted based on the B values (ascending) and after that, the rows with the same values sorted based on column C.

Comment: My idea is that I want 3 colums (ABC or XYZ) sorted based on X, then Y and then Z). first on X than on Y, then on Z. I hope this explains a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that first you need to translate your `A`,`B` and `C` lists into a list of `(x,y,z)` co-ordinates.  You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) like so:

```
coords = list(zip(A,B,C))
```

Then - sort the list in the way you wish, using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
coords_sorted_by_x = sorted(coords,key=lambda c:c[0])
[(3, 1, 2), (7, 8, 1), (9, 5, 1)]
coords_sorted_by_y = sorted(coords,key=lambda c:c[1])
[(3, 1, 2), (9, 5, 1), (7, 8, 1)]
coords_sorted_by_z = sorted(coords,key=lambda c:c[2])
[(9, 5, 1), (7, 8, 1), (3, 1, 2)]
```

If you need to retrieve the x,y and z co-ordinates into separate lists you can use [`zip(*)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) e.g.:

```
A_new, B_new, C_new = zip(*coords_sorted_by_z)
```

---

You note that you are using Python 2.7.  Although I heartily recommend that you use Python 3, the main difference is that you do not need to do `list(zip(...))` but simply `zip(...)`, because in python 2, `zip` returns a list.

As you will see if you run it, the code provided works for 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm using Py 2.7.10.

Comment: @almostgr Just give it a try - you'll notice it works for 2.7 too, but there is a slight difference in what `zip()` returns.  Answer updated to note that.

Comment: BTW @AlmostGr, if this answer solves your problem, please don't forget to click the check mark to mark it solved.

Comment: I will check it, thank you (all)

Comment: If you sort in several operations, you should reverse the order. The last key wins.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the default sort function available for Python lists.

```
    A.sort() // o/p : [3, 7, 9]
    B.sort() // o/p :  [1, 5, 8]
    C.sort() // o/p : [1, 1, 2]
```

Then doing the following should suffice:

```
    for e in zip(A,B,C):
        print e

    output:
        (3, 1, 1)
        (7, 5, 1)
        (9, 8, 2)
```

If need output in listformat:

```
    for e in zip(A,B,C):
        print list(e)

    output:
        [3, 1, 1]
        [7, 5, 1]
        [9, 8, 2]
```

Comment: Sorting the lists independently of each other will mess up the columns.

Answer (score 0):

So i am assuming that A is a list of x-, B of y- and C of z-coordinates. You want to sort the columns in your matrix, so that numbers stay vertically together.

First i would transpose your matrix:

```
matrix = [
  [9,3,7],
  [5,1,8],
  [1,2,1]
]
matrix = zip(*matrix)
```

and then sort this list. As zondo said, `sort` does what you want by default in this case:

```
matrix.sort()
```

And lastly transpose the matrix back:

```
matrix = zip(*matrix)
```